# SGD library for Java

Tags: java, gradient-descent, stochastic

Could someone recommend me lightweight, easy to use Java library for stochastic gradient descent optimization?

Comment: Have you tried to search this on google?

Comment: @C0dekid Yes I have and the results weren't  very satisfying. For example if you try to google "stochastic gradient descent library java" the first two results are some personal repos on GitHub. I suppose my question should have been more like what is the standard library for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a late reply. Try MLLib by apache (part of SPARK project) or WEKA. Only to optimize a linear regression, you might like to code yourself rather than going for a library.

Comment: Thank you for participating to Stack Overflow, however please note that the question you have answered is off-topic as per the [help/on-topic] since it is a tool request. Answers to such questions tend to be of [poor quality](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and quickly become stale (what might have been a good resource two years ago may simply not exist anymore). You can flag this question as off-topic by clicking the "flag" link once you have sufficient reputation.